# Problem with lights in blender 2.81

Tags: animation, light, lighting

I'm having some problems with a blender project, I'm trying to learn how to animate and I did this very simple barrel that falls: only problem is, I can't figure out why but there is way too many light in my simulation (There maybe is a more precise name for that), and I really can't work out why the light that I created does not seem to work. I tried to increase a lot it's watt and change color, and I even tried to get it closer to my object, but it simply does not seems to work and I don't understand why. I'm leaving the project file so if you want you can download it and try to give it a look.

[Project file (google drive)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Q651KTzv5aECCxrCiGjIlf7xZmWXDq21)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I looked at your file. There are some major problems, you are working on your lighting too soon. You have no materials applied to any of your objects. You need at least a basic material to setup lighting. Also your camera isn't placed very well to catch the action, it is barely getting the barrel at all. Fix these first then try to get the lighting. I would use a sunlamp, not the spot lamp.

Comment: Well of course I didn’t mean to render the scene with the camera and the light placed in that fashion, i was just trying to see if i could have an idea of what to do in the future. You say that using some texture and material i should not have problem of this kind?

Comment: There was only the one default light, if you have materials it will let Blender know beter what to do with the light and give you contrast as you adjust your lighting.